# WordPress Posts, order by custom table results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a blog that I need to re-order based on the number of values in a completely custom table. The reason I am not using meta data is a bit complex, but this is just what I need to do.

I just need to count the number of rows in the table `wp_upvotes` which have a `postID` that matches the `ID` of the WordPress blog post, and order it by most "upvotes" to least. This result should include the WordPress post even if there are no values in the `wp_upvotes` table.

The query I am trying is this:

```
$post = $wpdb->get_results("
     SELECT wp_posts.*, COUNT(wp_upvotes.id) AS upvotes
     FROM wp_posts 
     LEFT JOIN wp_upvotes 
               ON wp_posts.ID = wp_upvotes.postID 
               WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'  
               AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
      ORDER BY upvotes DESC, wp_posts.date DESC 
      LIMIT $pageNum, $numToLoad
  ", ARRAY_A);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that there is a match between each table, you are correct to use a `LEFT JOIN` - an easy way to think about it is that *everything* on the "left" (`wp_posts`) will be included, and things on the "right" (`wp_upvotes`) will be included if they have a match, otherwise null. Just using `JOIN` will ensure that rows from both tables will only be shown if there is a match.

My guess is that you need to include a `GROUP BY p.ID` to have each `upvotes` value specific to a particular post.

As a note, you also have an error using `wp_posts.date` instead of `wp_posts.post_date`;

It's also a good idea to use the `$wpdb-posts` and `$wpdb-prefix` properties in case you want to use this somewhere with a database prefix that is not `wp_`.

If you just want to see the results of the data in `wp_posts` you can just run a database query with an `ORDER BY` and return the columns, or if you want to use the WordPress filters (on things like `the_title()` and `the_content()` you can pass the post IDs into a WP_Query with the `post_id__in`  and `orderby=post__in` arguments - you would need to reference back the `$upvotes` value by ID however.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = <<<SQL;
    SELECT p.*, COUNT(v.id) as upvotes
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
    JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}upvotes v
      ON p.ID = v.postID
    WHERE 
      p.posts_status = 'publish'
      AND p.post_type = 'post'
    GROUP BY p.ID
    ORDER BY upvotes DESC, p.post_date DESC
    LIMIT $pageNum, $numToLoad
SQL;

// use ARRAY_A to access as $row['column'] instead of $row->column
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( $sql ); 
foreach ( $rows as $row ){
    $content = $row->post_content;
    $upvotes = $row->upvotes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your info and effort! But it doesn't seem to be working, it is not returning any results :(

Comment: Can you run it in a SQL tool? I just free formed it so possible that there is a syntax error, or perhaps `$pageNum` or `$numToLoad` aren't being set? Try removing them and see if it works.

Comment: It seems to be fine SQL, and those two values are indeed being set.

Comment: Then are you sure you have data in the database? :P I would do a visual check to make sure that you have published posts lined up to data in the upvote table, I just checked over it again and it *should* be working.

Comment: Yes there most certainly is data in the database

Comment: If you do a `LEFT JOIN` does it return any data?

Comment: No it does not unfortunately

Comment: If that doesn't work there are only 2 scenarios - no data in your posts table or they are posts but they dont have the right status/type.