# order wordpress posts by custom table results

Tags: php, wordpress

How to order by custom table with query in php ?

I'm trying to sort posts by the number of times an audio file has been played,
I have a custom table for counting "playcount",

I tried to use this code but it didn't work:

```
if ( isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == '4') {
global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_playcount ORDER BY 
playcount DESC');

$args = array(
'post_type'=>'download',
'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'orderby'   => $count,
'paged' => $paged
);}
```

$query = new WP_Query($args); if ( $query -> have_posts() ) : while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
get_template_part( 'tmp_parts/audio_store' );
endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();

[Query form phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1be2b.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680319/wordpress-posts-order-by-custom-table-results

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear what your problem is. Please edit the question to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve (with example output if necessary) and where you are getting stuck (with any error messages, and the output you are actually getting). That will help the community to assist you. Thank you.

Comment: Please identify what actually happens when you run your code (error messages, incorrect output) - 'it didn't work' is not something anyone can help you debug.

Comment: Hi MandyShaw,
No error messages but the output is not in the correct sequence, its like the query didn't recognize the compare value, i usually sort posts based on post meta value but here i didn't know how to sort em without a meta value or key.